# SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: leaked its continuation - for delegate?

Tags: swift, concurrency

I'm trying to extend my `class` with `async/await` capabilities, but at run-time there is an error in the console:

```
SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: query(_:) leaked its continuation!
```

Below is the `class` I'm trying to add the continuation to which uses a delegate:

```swift
class LocalSearch: NSObject, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    private let completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter
    private var completionContinuation: CheckedContinuation<[MKLocalSearchCompletion], Error>?

    init() {
        completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
        super.init()
        completer.delegate = self
    }

    func query(_ value: String) async throws -> [MKLocalSearchCompletion] {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            completionContinuation = continuation

            guard !value.isEmpty else {
                completionContinuation?.resume(returning: [])
                completionContinuation = nil
                return
            }

            completer.queryFragment = value
        }
    }

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        completionContinuation?.resume(returning: completer.results)
        completionContinuation = nil
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        completionContinuation?.resume(throwing: error)
        completionContinuation = nil
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```swift
let localSearch = LocalSearch()

do {
    let results = try await localSearch.query("toront")
    print(results)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Could it be you called `query` two times in a row, causing the continuation from the first call to be left "orphan"?

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a `if continuation == nil { continuation = ... }` but didn't make a difference.

Comment: That alone won't work, you **must** make sure the continuation is resumed, one way or another. Otherwise the `await` call for that continuation will never resume.

Answer (score 49):

This message appears if a continuation you created via `withCheckedContinuation`, or `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` doesn't report success or failure before being discarded. This is  will lead to resource leaking:

> Resuming from a continuation more than once is undefined behavior. **Never resuming leaves the task in a suspended state indefinitely, and leaks any associated resources.** CheckedContinuation logs a message if either of these invariants is violated.

Excerpt taken from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation) for `CheckedContinuation` (emphasis mine).

The problem is not just about having some resource leaks, never resuming a continuation means some `await` call will remain suspended forever, which, depending on your project architecture might be more or less problematic.

---

Here are possible causes for this to happen:

1. not all code paths resume the continuation, e.g. there is an `if`/`guard`/`case` that exits the scope without instructing the continuation to report success/failure

```swift
class Searcher {

    func search(for query: String) async throws -> [String] {
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            someFunctionCall(withCompletion: { [weak self] in
                guard let `self` = self else {
                    // if `result` doesn't have the expected value, the continuation
                    // will never report completion
                    return    
                }
                continuation.resume(returning: something)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

2. an "old"-style async function doesn't call the completion closure on all paths; this is a less obvious reason, and sometimes a harder to debug one:

```swift
class Searcher {
    private let internalSearcher = InternalSearcher()

    func search(for query: String) async throws -> [String] {
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            internalSearcher.search(query: query) { result in
                // everything fine here
                continuation.resume(returning: result)
            }
        }
    }
}

class InternalSearcher {

   func search(query: String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void {
        guard !query.isEmpty else {
            return
            // legit precondition check, however in this case,
            // the completion is not called, meaning that the
            // upstream function call will imediately discard
            // the continuation, without instructing it to report completion
        }

        // perform the actual search, report the results
    }
}
```

3. the continuation is stored as a property when a function is called; this means that if a second function call happens while the first one is in progress, then the first completion will be overwritten, meaning it will never report completion:

```swift
class Searcher {
    var continuation: CheckedContinuation<[String], Error>?

    func search(for query: String) async throws -> [String] {
        try await withCheckedTrowingContinuation { continuation in
            // note how a second call to `search` will overwrite the
            // previous continuation, in case the delegate method was
            // not yet called
            self.continuation = continuation
           
            // trigger the searching mechanism
        }
    }

    func delegateMethod(results: [String]) {
        self.continuation.resume(returning: results)
        self.continuation = nil
    }
}
```

#1 and #2 usually happen when dealing with functions that accept completion callbacks, while #3 usually happens when dealing with delegate methods, since in that case, we need to store the continuation somewhere outside the async function scope, in order to access it from the delegate methods.

Bottom line - try to make sure that a continuation reports completion on all possible code paths, otherwise, the continuation will indefinitely block the async call, leading to the task associated with that async call leaking its associated resources.

---

In your case, what likely happened is that a second `query()` call occurred before the first call had a chance to finish.

And in that case, the first continuation got discarded without reporting completion, meaning the first caller never continued the execution after the `try await query()` call, and this is not ok at all.

The following piece of code needs to be fixed, in order not to overwrite a pending continuation:

```
func query(_ value: String) async throws -> [MKLocalSearchCompletion] {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        completionContinuation = continuation
```

One quick solution would be to store an array of continuations, resume all continuations in the delegate methods, and clear the array afterward. Also, in your specific case, you could simply extract the validation out of the continuation code, as you are allowed to synchronously return/throw, even when in an async function:

```
func query(_ value: String) async throws -> [MKLocalSearchCompletion] {
    guard !value.isEmpty else {        
        return []
    }

    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        continuations.append(continuation)
        completer.queryFragment = value
    }
}

func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
    continuations.forEach { $0.resume(returning: completer.results) }
    continuations.removeAll() 
}

func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    continuations.forEach { $0.resume(throwing: error) }
    continuations.removeAll() 
}
```

I'd also strongly recommend converting your class to an actor, in order to avoid data races, regardless if you store one continuation, like now, or you use an array. The reason is that the continuation property is consumed from multiple threads and at some point you might end up with two threads concurrently accessing/writing the property.

Comment: Great answer! Do you have any pointers on your last suggestion of converting this example to use an actor?

Comment: @BenjaminHall first step would be to change the data type from `class` to `actor`, the compiler should guide you from there.

Comment: a lot of text but it is still unclear what to do when you use `[weak self]` inside `withCheckedContinuation` or its nested `Task`

Comment: @Gargo that depends on the specifics of your project. The continuation can be instructed to either return a value or throw an error, depending on which suits best for that particular use case.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is here -

```
func query(_ value: String) async throws -> [MKLocalSearchCompletion] {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        // storing into a variable makes this continuation instance outlive the scope of it
        // In other words, it leaks OR escapes the scope 
        // This is same as why we need to add @escaping attribute for callback functions arguments 
        // those are either stored in variables like this
        // or passed to other functions (escaping scope of current function)
        completionContinuation = continuation

        // Try commenting above line, the warning should go away
        // And your code will stop working as well :)
        // How to design this component is other question.
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

```
import MapKit

class LocalSearch: NSObject, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    typealias Completion = (_ results: [MKLocalSearchCompletion]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
    
    private let completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter
    private var completion: Completion?
    
    override init() {
        completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
        super.init()
        completer.delegate = self
    }
    
    func query(_ value: String, completion: @escaping Completion) {
        self.completion = completion
        completer.queryFragment = value
    }
    
    func query(_ value: String) async throws -> [MKLocalSearchCompletion] {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            
            guard !value.isEmpty else {
                continuation.resume(returning: [])
                return
            }
            
            self.query(value, completion: { (results, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(returning: results ?? [])
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        completion?(completer.results, nil)
    }
    
    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        completion?(nil, error)
    }
}
```

Comment: @TruMan1 The reason for warning still persisting after commenting this line is - there's NO WAY that continuation instance is now going to be completed EVER. Delegates callback can't resume it.

Comment: my previous got deleted, my comment was commenting out doesn't make the warning go away strangely enough. thx for the explanation

Comment: @TruMan1 See the **UPDATE**, I didn't compile it - you'll get the idea though.

Comment: This was a good thought to try, but very weird still same warning in the console about misuse. Maybe beta is not working or I'm doing something wrong.