# SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: leaked its continuation

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using the following function to do a fetch request using Alamofire:

```
func afRequest(url: URL) async throws -> Data {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        // timeoutInterval is in seconds
        AF.request(url, method: .get, requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = 10 }).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseData { response in
            
            if let data = response.data {
                continuation.resume(returning: data)
                return
            }
            
            guard case let .failure(error) = response.result else { return }
            
            switch error {
                case .invalidURL(let url):
                    print("Invalid URL: \(url) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I intentionally set the timeout to 10 seconds to test this out. So the error is `"The request timed out."`. After that I get this error:

```
SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: afRequest(url:) leaked its continuation!
```

I was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68145462/swift-task-continuation-misuse-leaked-its-continuation-for-delegate), but it's not clear what they accomplished or the solution. What is the proper way to mitigate this leak?

**Edit:**

This is how I switched the above part, but still says the same:

```
if case let .failure(error) = response.result {
    switch error {
        case .invalidURL(let url):
        ...

    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
    return
```

Edit 2 - here's the new handling of the error, but still says the same:

```
func afRequest(url: URL) async throws -> Data {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        // timeoutInterval is in seconds
        AF.request(url, method: .get, requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = .infinity }).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseData { response in
            
            if let data = response.data {
                continuation.resume(returning: data)
                return
            }
            
            if case let .failure(error) = response.result {
                switch error {
                    case .invalidURL(let url):
                        print("Invalid URL: \(url) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                   // There are more cases...
                        
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                        return
                }
            }
            else {
                  continuation.resume(throwing: Error.self as! Error)
                  return
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update to Alamofire 5.5 for built in `async` - `await` support.

Comment: I’ve upgraded but don’t really see a difference, can you post a solution with the new async function with error handling? @JonShier

Comment: You can read the documentation: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-alamofire-with-swift-concurrency

Comment: I did already before posting here, there is no a clear full example of how to do it @JonShier

Comment: There are several examples in the documentation, I'm not sure what you mean. `AF.request(...).serializingData()` gives you access to await able APIs like you have here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guard is capturing a case and not calling the continuation. You need to call the continuation (e.g. `continuation.resume(...)`) from all branches so that it is not leaked.

This early `return` is causing the issue

```
guard case let .failure(error) = response.result else { return }
```

In your example you would need to decide how to handle `response.data` being nil and `response.result` being success and then update your `guard` to invoke `continuation.resume(...)` appropriately.

Comment: I changed it to: `if case let .failure(error) = response.result {` and put the switch statement inside with the continuation throwing and return at the end and still says the same :/

Comment: and what do you mean by call the continuation from all branches?

Comment: Added some more detail to the answer

Comment: I changed it but it says the same, see my edited question above under Edit.

Comment: That looks to have the same issue. You need to ensure that every single branch in your logic calls the continuation. The change you made only calls the continuation in the case there is a failure. You need to add an `else` to your `if` statement and call the continuation in there.

Comment: After the if I wrote `else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: Error.self as! Error)
                    return
                }` and still says SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE leaked its continuation!

Comment: See in the question my Edit #2 where I wrote the whole function

Comment: Not sure `Error.self as! Error` will work - that crashes if I try that in a playground.

Comment: Honestly I just put that there to satisfy the `else` curiosity you said. That part never gets called

Comment: Hard to tell with just the code provided but where you have `// There are more cases...` are all of the cases ensuring to call `continuation.resume(...)`?

Comment: Based on your last comment I identified the problem. I reduced the number of cases to just print the error and called the continuation. It looks like I needed to write the continuation in all the cases, so instead of repeating all that code, I'll call it once. I'll accept your answer, change it to: `if case let .failure(error) = response.result {
                    print(" Error: \(error)")
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    return
                }` Or rather add and thanks for the help :)