# It works sometimes, but some throws error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred - Swift

Tags: swift

Until now I had no problems, which is the weird part. Swift never complained about this code. A user got an error signing up and me debugging put a print statement and maybe because of the introspection of the code now swift caught the error and is saying:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I thought this is how you handle continuation, what's wrong in my code?
The funny thing is that it works sometimes, others it throws the error above :/

The error is in line: `try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation`

Here's the full code:

```
// Signup
final func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String) async throws -> (message: String, didItSucceed: Bool) {
    print("➡️ About to sign up user")
    
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        let userAttributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email)]
        let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: userAttributes)
        
        _ = Amplify.Auth.signUp(
            username: username,
            password: password,
            options: options
        ) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let signUpResult):
                    print("✅ Signup confirmed. Next-> needs email verification from \(email)")
                    
                    switch signUpResult.nextStep {
                        case .done:
                            print("✅ Finished sign up!")
                        case .confirmUser(_, _):
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                // Confirm the Auth State to confirm code passing in the username to confirm
                                self.authState = .login
                            }
                            continuation.resume(returning: ("Check your Email ", true))
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    var errorMessageToTheUser = "Something went wrong "
                    print(error)
                    continuation.resume(returning: (errorMessageToTheUser, false))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If I remove the print() on top of the `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` the exception goes away. But the error when user signs up still remains and it crashes at line:

```
try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
```

and takes (the error) to the `@main struct` saying: Thread 1: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x46b56a8a6b20)`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation`. The `Checked` version is just for testing that you are doing everything correctly; it has overhead that you don't want to encounter unless you have to. (However, as we shall see, you are *not* doing everything correctly, so this was actually a good choice for the moment!)

Second, if you look at the docs, you will see that this is a generic function, whose type T is resolved through the resolution of the CheckedContinuation (your `continuation`). So instead of merely saying

```
continuation in
```

you can, if necessary, supply the type information:

```
(continuation: CheckedContinuation<WhatType, Error>) -> Void in
```

(I do not know what type you should put for WhatType because you have not given enough information.)

Third, you are crashing because you are using the continuation incorrectly. You *must* call `continuation.resume` exactly once on *every* possible path of exit within your implementation, and you are not doing that (look at the `.done` path for example). I think you will find that when you get this worked out, the other problems will just go away.

Fourth, the reason why the `print` statement changed everything is that before you put that there, there was an implicit `return` before your `try await`. Thanks to that, the compiler was able to infer the types in question. But you took that away when you added the `print`. If you put `return try await` your compilation problems might all go away (though you will still crash because you are not using the continuation properly).

Comment: Reading your comments now, the type I'm returning is on the function, it would be (String, Bool)

Comment: It's funny that I asked long ago when using the continuation and they told me the opposite, that I should not be using `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation`. How would I return String and Bool? I tried this: `try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<String, Bool, Error>) ->` but doesn't work.

Comment: Ok so with your comments and a little bit of thinking this is how I got it to work, please check if it's correct: `return try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { (continuation: UnsafeContinuation<(message: String, didItSucceed: Bool), Error>) -> Void in` EDIT: Keeps throwing error :/

Comment: You beat me to it! Nice, but I would think hard before doing that. Remember, the whole point of `throws` is that you signal failure by throwing. Returning a String-and-a-Bool should not be necessary. Either you return a string or you throw. So I'd say rethink your whole architecture on this method.

Comment: It still throws the error tho :/

Comment: What "error" does it "throw"?  — Please keep in mind that you are not supplying enough information about your code or what the issue is, so I've had to do all this by guesswork because I can't actually attempt to compile or run your code on my own machine. Try to cut some slack for the people who you are asking to help you.

Comment: As soon as it hits the try line, it crashes, and the error appears in @main with message: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x46b56a8a6b20)`

Comment: Where would this log be generated? I'm using xcode locally with the simulator. I'm looking at `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` but there is nothing after the crash

Comment: What about the Xcode console though? I would expect to see _some_ sort of statement of what's happening.

Comment: So it looks like you were told all this back at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407853/swift-task-continuation-misuse-leaked-its-continuation but you still didn't do what you were told?