SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: - method leaked its continuation! - Not blocking main thread?
I have to use async/await with withCheckedThrowingContinuation to get a result from an external lib (I cannot modify this lib).
I call this from a UIViewController (which means the Task will be on the MainActor if I understood correctly).
But the call to the external lib sometimes prints SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: leaked its continuation, which means its completion will not be called if I understood correctly, and the code after this is not executed. It happens especially when I spam the button.
My first question is, why can I still use the main thread if the code after is never executed ? Shouldn't the main thread be blocked there waiting for it's completion ?
My second question is, how does the system know that the completion will never be called ? Does it track if the completion is retained in the external lib at runtime, if the owner of the reference dies, it raises this leak warning ?
My third question is, could this lead to a crash ? Or the system just cancel the Task and I shouldn't worry about it ?
And my last question is, what can I do if I cannot modify the external lib ?
Here's a sample of my code :
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    func onButtonTap() {
        Task {
             do {
                 try await callExternalLib() // <--- This can be called after the leak
             }
        }
    }
    
    func callExternalLib() async throws {

         print("Main thread") // <--- This is always called on the main thread

         try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
              myExternalLib.doSomething {
                   continuation.resume()
              }, { error in
                   continuation.resume(throwing: error)
              }
         }

         print("Here thread is unlocked") // <--- This is never called when it leaks
    }
}



the issue is that myExternalLib.doSomething is returning more than once or there is a return and an error which is likely the case since try is likely preventing the print from running.

"Does it track if the completion is retained in the external lib at runtime, if the owner of the reference dies, it raises this leak warning?" Indeed, this is logged from a deinit. See CheckedContinuation.swift.

I think to solve this problem we need to know more about that external library. Presumably what is happening here is that library throws away the previous closure when doSomething is called again. Does it provide a way to check whether doSomething is called and hasn't completed? Or does it provide a way to cancel whatever doSomething is currently running?

At worst, you need to write a wrapper around myExternalLib that tracks whether doSomething is currently "running". This could be as simple as a Bool flag. If doSomething is running and it is called again, call the completion handler immediately to return an error.

Is myExternalLib a local variable or an instance variable? We can't guess what's the real code of myExternalLib, but a guard let self else { return } might causes that error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68145462/swift-task-continuation-misuse-leaked-its-continuation-for-delegate so if myExternalLib is a local var, you won't pass the guard let self, hence your error... Do you absolutely need async/await in your scenario?


My first question is, why can I still use the main thread if the code after is never executed ?
Shouldn't the main thread be blocked there waiting for it's completion ?

That's not how Swift Concurrency works.
The whole concept / idea behind Swift Concurrency is that the current thread is not blocked by an await call.
To put it briefly and very simply, you can imagine an asynchronous operation as a piece of work that is processed internally on threads. However, while waiting for an operation, other operations can be executed because you're just creating a suspension point. The whole management and processing of async operations is handled internally by Swift.
In general, with Swift Concurrency you should refrain from thinking in terms of “threads”, these are managed internally and the thread on which an operation is executed is deliberately not visible to the outside world.
In fact, with Swift Concurrency you are not even allowed to block threads without further ado, but that's another topic.
If you want to learn more details about async/await and the concepts implemented by Swift, I recommend reading SE-0296 or watching one of the many WWDC videos Apple has published on this topic.

My second question is, how does the system know that the completion will never be called ?
Does it track if the completion is retained in the external lib at runtime, if the owner of the reference dies, it raises this leak warning ?

See the official documentation:

Missing to invoke it (eventually) will cause the calling task to remain suspended indefinitely which will result in the task “hanging” as well as being leaked with no possibility to destroy it.


The checked continuation offers detection of mis-use, and dropping the last reference to it, without having resumed it will trigger a warning. Resuming a continuation twice is also diagnosed and will cause a crash.

For the rest of your questions, I assume that you have shown us all the relevant parts of the code.

My third question is, could this lead to a crash ? Or the system just cancel the Task and I shouldn't worry about it ?

Only multiple calls to a continuation would lead to a crash (see my previous answer).
However, you should definitely make sure that the continuation is called, otherwise you will create a suspension point that will never be resolved. Think of it like an operation that is never completed and thus causes a leak.

And my last question is, what can I do if I cannot modify the external lib ?

According to the code you have shown us, there is actually only one possibility:
Calling doSomething multiple times causes calls to the same method that are still running to be canceled internally by the library and therefore the completion closures are never called.
You should therefore check the documentation of doSomething to see what it says about multiple calls and cancelations.
In terms of what you could do if the library doesn't give you a way to detect cancelations:

Prevent multiple calls of the method. This is probably the simplest solution, you could, for example, simply deactivate the button while the library method is still running.
If you want to deliberately allow multiple calls, you must detect these cases and complete any unfulfilled continuations.

Here is a very simple code example that should demonstrate how you can solve the problem for this case (2):
private var pendingContinuation: (UUID, CheckedContinuation<Void, any Error>)?

func callExternalLib() async throws {
    if let (_, continuation) = pendingContinuation {
        self.pendingContinuation = nil
        continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
    }

    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        let continuationID = UUID()
        pendingContinuation = (continuationID, continuation)

        myExternalLib.doSomething {
            Task { @MainActor in
                if let (id, continuation) = self.pendingContinuation, id == continuationID {
                    self.pendingContinuation = nil
                    continuation.resume()
                }
            }
        } error: { error in
            Task { @MainActor in
                if let (id, continuation) = self.pendingContinuation, id == continuationID {
                    self.pendingContinuation = nil
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Note that this solution assumes that there are no other scenarios in which doSomething never calls its completion handlers.

Thanks a lot for this solution ! Just wondering though, what's the purpose of storing a UUID and not just the continuation ?

If you're using an actor with a serial executor (like MainActor) then this is probably not necessary. When you get into the callbacks of doSomething, you have to make sure that you are also using the continuation that belongs to the original call. Imagine that there are 2 calls to callExternalLib. The first gets to the code location myExternalLib.doSomething and then waits. Then a second call is made that overwrites the pendingContinuation and immediately afterwards the completion handler of the first call is called. You would now call the wrong continuation without the UUID.

Or to summarize it briefly: it prevents race conditions.

Forget the caveat that you might not need it. You always need the UUID to prevent a race condition from occurring when calling the continuation. The doSomething completion handler of call 1 should never call the continuation of call 2 and vice versa.

tl;dr
The library apparently does not handle concurrent requests correctly. So, you must avoid running requests concurrently by either:

Preventing concurrent requests altogether (e.g., disable the button until the prior request finishes);
Making the multiple requests run sequentially, rather than concurrently;
If you must run concurrent requests; use separate instances of the external library for each; or
If you want to run another request, cancel the prior one (if the library even provides such an interface).

I have mocked up an external library that manifests this problem, so you can see what might be going on, below. I also provide a little more detail on these four options.

You said:

But the call to the external lib sometimes prints SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: leaked its continuation, which means its completion will not be called if I understood correctly, and the code after this is not executed. It happens especially when I spam the button.

The library apparently does not handle concurrent requests.
This can easily happen if the library does something naïve, such as saving completion-handler closures in properties which are called later. For example, here is a contrived example that manifests this problem:
class ExternalLibrary {
    private var successClosure: (() -> Void)?
    private var failureClosure: ((any Error) -> Void)?

    func doSomething(onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onFailure: @escaping (any Error) -> Void) {
        successClosure = onSuccess
        failureClosure = onFailure

        performAsynchronousWork()
    }
}

private extension ExternalLibrary {
    func performAsynchronousWork() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) { [self] in
            didFinish(with: nil)
        }
    }

    // maybe this is some delegate method that the async work calls

    func didFinish(with error: (any Error)?) {
        if let error {
            failureClosure?(error)
        } else {
            successClosure?()
        }

        successClosure = nil
        failureClosure = nil
    }
}

This looks logical enough, but it has a problem: If doSomething is called again before the prior request finishes, the library’s saved closures can be (incorrectly) replaced with new ones. The net effect will be that first set of closures may not be called at all; the second set of closures can even end up getting called multiple times!
Yes, this is a problem for our continuation-wrapping pattern, but, more generally, it is a bad design for any asynchronous pattern. The caller of the library needs to be confident that one or the other of the two closures are guaranteed to be called once and only once, but this apparently is not the case here.
Now, whether this is exactly what your external library is doing is obviously unclear, but either way, it is just an anti-pattern. A well-written library would either:

enforce the prohibition of concurrent requests, e.g., if a prior request is still underway, the subsequent call might immediately calling the error completion handler closure, preventing the concurrent requests;

be modified to support concurrent requests; or

be modified to support cancellation so the app developer has a way to cancel a prior request before initiating another.


All of these are fairly simple fixes, but I presume that because this is an external library, these options are off the table for you in the short-term.
So, I would advise opening a ticket with he provider of that library.

Until the library is fixed to support concurrent requests, the burden rests upon your shoulders to simply avoid concurrent requests. There are a variety of approaches:

The easiest way would be to avoid concurrent requests entirely by disabling the button while the request is underway:
func onButtonTap(_ button: UIButton) {
    button.isEnabled = false

    Task {
        defer { button.isEnabled = true }

        try await callExternalLib()
    }
}


If you quickly tap the button, say, five times in rapid succession, and you really want the external library to run its routine five times, then you might make the tasks to run sequentially. The easiest way to do this would be an AsyncChannel from the Swift Async Algorithms package.
So, you’d create a channel:
let channel = AsyncChannel<Void>()

You would monitor that channel:
for try await _ in channel {
    try await callExternalLib()
}

And then, on a button tap, you would send to your channel:
func onButtonTap(_ button: UIButton) {
    Task { await self.channel.send(()) }
}

So, a full MRE of this pattern would be:
import UIKit
import AsyncAlgorithms

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var monitorTask: Task<Void, any Error>?
    let externalLibrary = ExternalLibrary()
    let channel = AsyncChannel<Void>()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        startMonitoring()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        stopMonitoring()
    }

    @IBAction func onButtonTap(_ button: UIButton) {
        Task { await self.channel.send(()) }
    }
}

// MARK: - Private implementation

private extension ViewController {
    func startMonitoring() {
        guard monitorTask == nil else { return } // if accidentally called when already running, don’t start again, losing reference to old task

        monitorTask = Task {
            for try await _ in channel {
                try await callExternalLib()
            }
        }
    }

    func stopMonitoring() {
        monitorTask?.cancel()
        monitorTask = nil
    }

    func callExternalLib() async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            externalLibrary.doSomething {
                continuation.resume()
            } onFailure: { error in
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}

The only interesting thing to note here is that you do not want to rely upon deinit to cancel your asynchronous sequence, but rather start the monitoring of the channel when the view appears and cancel it when the view is ultimately dismissed.

Another approach would be to have separate instances of the external library. So we might lose the shared property, myExternalLibrary, and instead use a local instance:
func onButtonTap() {
    Task {
        try await callExternalLib() // <--- This can be called after the leak
    }
}

func callExternalLib() async throws {
     try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
          let localLibraryInstance = ExternalLibrary() // use a local instance rather than some shared instance

          localLibraryInstance.doSomething {
               continuation.resume()
          } onFailure: { error in
               continuation.resume(throwing: error)
          }
     }
}

Not all libraries will support this pattern. Things like URLSession do (keeping the instance alive until the request is done), but other do not. If not, you could maintain a collection (an array or dictionary) of instances of the external library.

The fourth approach would be to cancel the previous doSomething before submitting another. When wrapping the completion-handler-closure-based call in a withCheckedThrowingContinuation, you’d also wrap that in a withTaskCancellationHandler. E.g.,
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var externalLibraryTask: Task<Void, any Error>?
    let externalLibrary = ExternalLibrary()

    @IBAction func onButtonTap(_ button: UIButton) {
        externalLibraryTask?.cancel()

        externalLibraryTask = Task {
            try await self.callExternalLib()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Private implementation

private extension ViewController {
    func callExternalLib() async throws {
        try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
                externalLibrary.doSomething {
                    continuation.resume()
                } onFailure: { error in
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        } onCancel: {
            …
        }
    }
}

But, this pattern only works if the external library supports cancellation at all. I might wager that if they failed to handle something as basic as concurrent requests, they probably have not contemplated cancellation support, either. We simply cannot comment further without more details about this external library.
But, I include this for the sake of completeness.


Now, which of these make sense in your case, we cannot say, as the question was a bit too abstract. But those are a few workarounds.

To answer your follow-up questions:

My first question is, why can I still use the main thread if the code
after is never executed ? Shouldn't the main thread be blocked there
waiting for it's completion ?

No, an await does not block an actor. It suspends the current function’s execution, but frees the actor to carry on and do other work. Actors are “reentrant”. See Actor Reentrancy in SE-0306.

My second question is, how does the system know that the completion
will never be called ? Does it track if the completion is retained in
the external lib at runtime, if the owner of the reference dies, it
raises this leak warning?

When the last reference to the continuation is removed (i.e., the third party library releases those closures), the system verifies whether the continuation has been called or not. If not, you get this warning.

My third question is, could this lead to a crash ? Or the system just
cancel the Task and I shouldn't worry about it ?

If you used the “unsafe” rendition, withUnsafe[Throwing]Continuation it would crash. It will not crash when using the “checked” rendition.
But that does not mean you should not fix it. See SE-0300, which says:

Instead of leading to undefined behavior, CheckedContinuation will instead trap if the program attempts to resume the continuation multiple times. CheckedContinuation will also log a warning if the continuation is discarded without ever resuming the task, which leaves the task stuck in its suspended state, leaking any resources it holds.

Bottom line, you want to heed the warning and resolve the issue.

Thanks a lot for all these infos Rob! I accepted ITGuy answer as it fits more my needs, but your workarounds were great as well! And thank you for all the detailed answers these were really helpful. I wish I could accept two answers haha
